# Populating Value from table A into Table B

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a sourcetable in which I have  a field  `creation_date`  and another filed `Podium_date` along with other fields .

Now the business logic is  if the `creation_date` from source table  is null then the field in the target table (DW_Start_date) should be populated as `Podium_date`(which is a source field)  can anyone help me writing the logic in Hive or SQL

Note 1: I have two tables source table and a target table and I am trying to populate the data from source table to target table

Note 2: There is no primary key in the source  table This logic has to run trough all the data in the source table and should update the target table field  `DW_Start_date`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the target field DW_Start_date from the SQL sentence you can use `ISNULL(creation_date, Podium_date)`, this will return creation_date if it is not null, and Podium_date otherwise.

You can have a look at the sintaxis [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp). It would be something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO target_table(DW_Start_date, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT ISNULL(creation_date, Podium_date), column2, column3, ...
FROM source_table
```